# TypeError: res.redirect is not a function

Tags: javascript, fetch, response

No entiendo porque el siguiente código da error:

```
fetch('page1.html').then(function (res){
      res.redirect('page2.html', 302);// TypeError: res.redirect is not a funcition 
});
```

Según https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirect es un error de estado de redireccionamiento. Aunque no entiendo por qué. ¿Alguien me puede decir por qué?

Comment: 302 no es un error, es el código de estado HTTP `Found` (_encontrado_). En lo que sí te da error (en teoría) es en `res.redirect` (por eso lo de `TypeError: res.redirect is not a function`).

Comment: Y porqué res.redirect da error?

Comment: ¿Ese `fetch` está dentro de otra función?

Comment: No no lo esta. ¿El servidor puede modificar la manera en como se comporta el método res.redirect()?